# How to remove circularities in Excel with a UDF

Tags: excel, vba

My excel has an intended circularity in it. i.e.

- A = B + 2.
- B = A * 0.01

The circularity can be eliminated by pasting the *values* of A into a new range, and linking B to these values (and repeating a few times so the answer converges).

```
Sub paste_loop()

    For i = 1 to 10
        Range("A_paste").value = Range("A_copy").value
    Next i

End Sub
```

I want to avoid using a Sub and prefer to have this as a UDF that runs automatically. I set the formula is range "A_paste" equal to {=Equals("A_copy")}

```
Function Equals(a As String) As Variant

    Equals = Range(a)

End Function
```

However, Excel is smart enough to detect a circularity when doing a full calculate. Is there a way to get the result of the first macro into a UDF?

(I don't want to have a Macro that runs upon a user action, like opening the sheet, or to allow circularities/iteration in Excel)

Comment: How many circular calculations do you want to allow? 1, 5, 100, <until Excel blows up>?

Comment: Why not just [change the number of iterations](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-73fc7dac-91cf-4d36-86e8-67124f6bcce4) for circular references?

Comment: The statements "My excel has an intended circularity in it" and "I don't want ... to allow circularities/iteration in Excel" seem to be contradictory.  For your example, do you want `A` and `B` to end up with values of `1` and `.01`, or `3` and `1`, or `2` and `.02`, or do you need to goal seek and get `2.020202020202020202...` and `0.020202020202020202...`?  (Or just substitute one equation into the other so that you get either B=2/99 or A=200/99, depending on which way you do the substitution.)

Comment: In response to the above comments, circularities are not preferred but in my field of work (project finance) they can be unavoidable. Best practice is to have as few circular rows as possible (2-5) throughout the worksheet. The correct answer is 2.020202020 and 0.0202020202. One should not "allow circular references" (a Formula option in Excel) because it hides errors throughout the file. The macro, or the UDF are both explicit treatments. isolated to the rows in which they are used.